# ¿error al usar el diff en fechas con php?

Tags: php, date, diff

Actualmente estoy usando el comando diff en php para sacar una diferencia de dos meses, pero esa diferencia sale pero es erronea no es la correcta:

Fecha hoy: `8-03-18`  fecha futura: `07-05-18`

Este es el resultado que me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El recuadro de enmedio es el que se supone finge como contador en reversa entre ambas fechas, pero en vez de decir 10 meses deberia de decir 1 mes y el de dias 29 dias.

Codigo

```
<?php

$hoy = date('j-m-y');
$despues='07-05-18';
$horafutura='00:00';

$d1 = new DateTime($hoy);
$d2 = new DateTime($despues);


$interval = $d2->diff($d1);


echo '<div class="horario">'.$interval->format('%y years %m months %d days').'</div>';

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola! Tal vez tenga que ver con el formato en el que van las fechas al momento de instanciarlas como objetos DateTime. Mi sugerencia es que uses el formato clásico de año-mes-día, sólo para probar.

```
$hoy = date('Y-m-d');
$despues='2018-05-07';
$horafutura='00:00';
```

(Si restas las fechas como las tienes ahora, asumiendo que PHP piensa que el primer valor es el año; el segundo, el mes; y el tercero, el día, puede que sí te den los 10 meses...).

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.construct.php) no esta reconociendo correctamente el formato de la fecha ingresado.

### Solución:

Podrías usar [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) para indicar el formato en el que viene la fecha y así poder calcular correctamente la diferencia.

Ademas, debes calcular la diferencia a partir de  `$d1`, de lo contrario el resultado sería con un día de más.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$hoy = date('j-m-y');
$despues='07-05-18';
$horafutura='00:00';

$d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-m-y', $hoy);
$d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-m-y', $despues);

$interval = $d1->diff($d2);


echo '<div class="horario">'.$interval->format('%y years %m months %d days').'</div>';
```